# disable width to inherit other divs

Tags: css, html, web

basically i have a css code that sets the background and adjusts it to the best position that i've found (to not see borders of the image,etc).
but i have to set that image as an background, so i did the main div and set the class that have the background

```
.bgimg{
    background-image: url(https://d2v9y0dukr6mq2.cloudfront.net/video/thumbnail/acgu0vt/crystalline-motion-background-crystalized-movement-ice-sheets-blood-red_bbmkzqinp__F0000.png);
    height: 100%;
    width:  110%;

    transform-origin: center;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0 , 0;

    background-size: cover;
}
```

and thats fine until i get to this problem. when i put things inside this div, the width of it gets stretched to 110%.
so my wondering was, how do i disable this property to get inherited?
or maybe other approaches, like setting the background without having to be inside a div or body.

Answer (score 0):

i applied it to a new div above the main div with this properties.

```
.bgimg{
height: 100%;
width:  110%;
top: 0px; 
left: 0px;
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
background-size: cover;}
```